# Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeção de recurso no bean gerenciado estadoController

Tags: java, jsf

Quando tento rodar o java, ocorre esse erro.

Vou mandar o código.

MODEL:

```
package com.pi.drogaria.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Estado extends Codigo{

    @Column(length = 2, nullable = false)
    private String sigla;

    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }

    public void setSigla(String sigla) {
        this.sigla = sigla;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
package com.pi.drogaria.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.omnifaces.util.Messages;

import com.pi.drogaria.DAO.EstadoDAO;
import com.pi.drogaria.model.Estado;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EstadoController implements Serializable {
    private Estado estado;
    private List<Estado> estados;

    public Estado getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public List<Estado> getEstados() {
        return estados;
    }

    public void setEstados(List<Estado> estados) {
        this.estados = estados;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void listar() {
        try {
            EstadoDAO estadoDAO = new EstadoDAO();
            estados = estadoDAO.listar();
        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            Messages.addGlobalError("Erro ao listar estados.");
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void novo() {
        estado = new Estado();
            estados = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void salvar() {
        try {
            EstadoDAO estadoDAO = new EstadoDAO();
            estadoDAO.merge(estado);
            novo();
            estados = estadoDAO.listar();
            Messages.addGlobalInfo("Estado salvo com sucesso.");
        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            Messages.addGlobalError("Erro ao salvar estado.");
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void excluir(ActionEvent evento) {
        try {
            estado = (Estado) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("estadoSelecionado");
            EstadoDAO estadoDAO = new EstadoDAO();
            estadoDAO.excluir(estado);
            estados = estadoDAO.listar();
            Messages.addGlobalInfo("Estado removido com sucesso");
        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu erro ao tentar remover");
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void editar(ActionEvent evento){
        estado = (Estado) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("estadoSelecionado");
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Estados</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

  <p:growl id="mensagem" />

  <h:form id="formListagem">

    <p:panel header="Estados - Listagem">
      <p:dataTable id="tabela" emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado." paginator="true" value="#{EstadoController.estados}" var="estado" rows="5">
        <f:facet name="header">
          <p:commandButton value="Novo" oncomplete="PF('dialogo').show();" actionListener="#{EstadoController.novo}" update=":formCadastro:painel" />
        </f:facet>

        <p:column headerText="Nome" filterBy="#{estado.nome}">
          <h:outputText value="#{estado.nome}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Sigla" filterBy="#{estado.sigla}">
          <h:outputText value="#{estado.sigla}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Opções">
          <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{EstadoController.excluir}" update=":mensagem :formListagem:tabela">
            <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Deseja excluir o estado?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
            <f:attribute name="estadoSelecionado" value="#{estado}" />
          </p:commandButton>

          <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" actionListener="#{EstadoController.editar}" update=":formCadastro:painel" oncomplete="PF('dialogo').show();">
            <f:attribute name="estadoSelecionado" value="#{estado}" />
          </p:commandButton>

        </p:column>

      </p:dataTable>

      <p:confirmDialog global="true">
        <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
      </p:confirmDialog>

    </p:panel>
  </h:form>

  <p:dialog header="Estados - Cadastro" widgetVar="dialogo" draggable="false" resizable="false" modal="true" closable="false">
    <h:form id="formCadastro">

      <h:panelGrid id="painel" columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel value="Nome:" />
        <p:inputText maxlength="50" size="30" value="#{EstadoController.estado.nome}" />

        <p:outputLabel value="Sigla:" />
        <p:inputText maxlength="2" size="10" value="#{EstadoController.estado.sigla}" />
      </h:panelGrid>

      <h:panelGrid columns="2">

        <p:commandButton value="Salvar" actionListener="#{EstadoController.salvar}" update=":mensagem :formCadastro:painel :formListagem:tabela" />
        <p:commandButton value="Fechar" oncomplete="PF('dialogo').hide();" />

      </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
  </p:dialog>
</h:body>

</html>
```

ERRO:

```
  com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeção de recurso no bean gerenciado estadoController
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.calculateFirst(UIData.java:215)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:186)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:90)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1152)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.pi.drogaria.util.HibernateUtil.criarFabricaDeSessoes(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    at com.pi.drogaria.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
    at com.pi.drogaria.DAO.DAOGenerico.listar(DAOGenerico.java:41)
    at com.pi.drogaria.controller.estadoController.listar(estadoController.java:43)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error accessing stax stream
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
    at com.pi.drogaria.util.HibernateUtil.criarFabricaDeSessoes(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[29,36]
Message: Fim prematuro do arquivo.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:103)
    ... 76 more
```

CLASSE CODIGO:

```
package com.pi.drogaria.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class Codigo implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long codigo;

        public Long getCodigo() {
            return codigo;
        }

        public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
            this.codigo = codigo;
        }

        public String ToString() {
            return String.format("%s[codigo=%d]", getClass().getSimpleName(), getCodigo());
        }

    }
```

HIBERNATE UTIL:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory fabricaDeSessoes = criarFabricaDeSessoes();

public static SessionFactory getFabricaDeSessoes() {
    return fabricaDeSessoes;
}

private static SessionFactory criarFabricaDeSessoes() {
    try {
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = 
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata metaData = 
                new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
        fabricaDeSessoes = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        System.err.println("A fábrica de sessões não pode ser criada." + th);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
    }
    return fabricaDeSessoes;
}
```

HIBERNATE.CFG.XML:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
```

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">12345</property>

<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name="format_sql">false</property>

<mapping class="com.pi.drogaria.model.Cidade"/>
<mapping class="com.pi.drogaria.model.Cliente"/>
<mapping class="com.pi.drogaria.model.Estado"/>
<mapping class="com.pi.drogaria.model.Fabricante"/>
<mapping class="com.pi.drogaria.model.Funcionario"/>
<mapping class="com.pi.drogaria.model.ItemVenda"/>
<mapping class="com.pi.drogaria.model.Pessoa"/>
<mapping class="com.pi.drogaria.model.Produto"/>
<mapping class="com.pi.drogaria.model.Usuario"/>
<mapping class="com.pi.drogaria.model.Venda"/>
```

ERRO AO TENTAR SALVAR UM ESTADO:

```
    ago 17, 2018 9:26:16 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase execute
ADVERTÊNCIA: /pages/estados.xhtml @75,48 value="#{EstadoController.estado.nome}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'EstadoController' resolved to null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/estados.xhtml @75,48 value="#{EstadoController.estado.nome}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'EstadoController' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getConverter(ComponentUtils.java:146)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.Dialog.processValidators(Dialog.java:424)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1152)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'EstadoController' resolved to null
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:74)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:58)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:174)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
    ... 38 more

ago 17, 2018 9:26:16 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
GRAVE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/estados.xhtml @75,48 value="#{EstadoController.estado.nome}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'EstadoController' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getConverter(ComponentUtils.java:146)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.Dialog.processValidators(Dialog.java:424)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1152)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'EstadoController' resolved to null
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:74)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:58)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:174)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Esse é todo o stacktrace que você recebeu ou só uma parte? A falha na criação do bean é provavelmente apenas um sintoma de outro erro que ocorreu antes da tentativa de criá-lo.

Comment: Voce colocou duas vezes a classe estadoController, coloca a classe Codigo

Comment: Desculpa, errei, corrigi, agora esta com o view.

Comment: O outro erro é do hibernateUtil, porém acho que é problema que meu postgreSQL não quer pegar e vou esperar meu professor corrigir esse erro, para poder usar o eclipse com o postgreSQL, ai tirei o final do que informava o erro de hibernateUtil, porém, se mesmo assim quiser, posso enviar o final para visualizar o stacktrace por completo.

Comment: Coloca sua classe Codigo também

Comment: Coloquei a classe Código

Comment: Implementa os métodos equals e hashcode na classe Codigo. Mas por causa desse erro: *Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[29,36]* acredito que um dos seus problemas esta na configuração do seu xml

Comment: @Lucas Fica como dica: sempre que você tiver uma stacktrace de erros, nunca tire nenhuma parte dela, sempre a informe totalmente. A origem dos erros numa stacktrace vai de baixo para cima, então se você tira uma parte, você impede que o real motivo do problema possa ser visualizado, ok?

Comment: Edjane, nesse caso seria o web.xml? eu coloquei o equals e hashcode no Código, é engraçado esse erro surgir agora, formatei o notebook, quando instalei eclipse e coloquei o jboss e tomcat e coloquei a pasta do meu projeto, ele veio com esse erro, antes ele pegava normalmente, sem esse erro, agora vem com esse erro.

Comment: StatelessDev, ok, entendido, exclui por achar que não era tão necessário por está falando de HIbernateUtil e a questão da dúvida era só o erro fora disso, por saber que minha fabrica de sessão ou algo relacionado ao postgreSQL não ia pegar para salvar no banco, que ia resolver com meu professor na semana que vem... mas enfim... foi colocado, foi mal ai!

Comment: Poste o código do seu método `com.pi.drogaria.util.HibernateUtil.criarFabricaDeSessoes(...)` e o seu XML do Hibernate também.

Comment: Adicionado. só tenho esse problema de injeção de BEAN com controller. Porém esta tudo correto, não sei porque não mostra a tela.

Comment: Olá Lucas, primeiro o nome do seu arquivo esta assim? *HIBERNET.CFG.XML* acredito que não, pois ele esta dando o local do erro ***[row,col]:[29,36]***, vai no seu arquivo *hibernate.cfg.xml* verifica se a classe declarada na linha 29 esta conforme a classe do seu projeto, qualquer coisa comenta a linha 29 e veja o resultado.

Comment: Oi, Edjane, só escrevi errado aqui, mas no projeto em si, estava correto HIBERNATE.CFG.XML, só escrevi errado, mas editei para colocar nome certo, mas realmente já olhei tudo, e não acho solução alguma, já exclui 4 eclipse e coloquei outros para ver se o problema é no eclipse, mas creio que não, pode ser JSF, mas se for ai não sei como corrigir para colocar para funcionar essa, "injeção de Bean".

Comment: O que tem na linha 29 do seu hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: @Edjane fechamento da tag </hibernate-configuration>

Comment: Verifiquei que no seu estadoController você não inicializa seus dados, então como vai ficar grande aqui, vou colocar  como resposta o que acho que pode lhe ajudar. Mas acho estranho porque você falou que esse projeto rodava antes de formatar o computador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta fazer assim:

1. na sua classe ***estadoController*** inicie o nome de uma classe
   sempre com letra maiúscula;
2. inicialize suas variáveis estado e estados, você pode fazer isso no método construtor pois ele sempre será executado quando for instanciado um objeto dessa classe, segue um exemplo de como você pode fazer isso:

Vi que você criou um método chamado novo() que você usar para limpar os dados no formulário, certo?

```
public void novo() {
  estado = new Estado();
  estados = new ArrayList<>(); //adicione essa linha para limpar a lista de estados
}
```

Cria um método contrutor na sua classe EstadoController

```
//Aqui, seguindo a padronização, já considerei a classe iniciada com letra maiuscula
public EstadoController(){
  //chama o método novo
  novo();
}
```

Faz essas alterações e fale o resultado, pois como você disse que formatou o computador e que antes disso funcionava pode ter outros problemas.

Comment: eu consegui resolver não sei como, acho que por mudar para começar com letra maiúscula ... Só que agora ele não quer salvar... da erro em uma linha no xhtml com o controller... refiz tudo e continuou assim com esse erro... vou postar o novo erro, se souber o que pode ser que ta dando erro, fico grato. Obrigado pela ajuda desde já!

Comment: Vi o novo erro, quando você chama o objeto do seu bean na página JSF, você está chamando assim: ***#{EstadoController.estado.nome}*** por padrão a classe é iniciada com letra maiúscula mas a chamada do bean na página JSF é iniciada com letra minúscula ***#{estadoController.estado.nome}***

Comment: eu vi isso, corrigi, mas infelizmente meu projeto ou meu computador, não sei... voltou a dar problema com injeção de recuso Bean, isso realmente está me desanimando, o projeto pegar quando quer? Ai faz ele todo sem testar par ver se ta pegando correto, quando chegar no dia da apresentação do projeto ele não abrir... complicado surgir um problema sem solução nenhuma... realmente fica sem saber o que fazer, pegou ontem a noite, agora de manhã volta o problema de injeção de Bean, pegar quando quer.